# Steering wheel won't align straight after turning - 2007 Honda Jazz

Tags: honda, steering, alignment, jazz, suspension-geometry

My friend bought a 10-y.o. Honda Jazz recently (Honda Fit in the U.S. AFAIK). Normally, after turning, the wheels should "align themselves" straight thanks to suspension geometry - in his car, you have to manually turn the wheel back for the last 15-20°. Is it possible that it was like this from factory, or is there something wrong with the front suspension?

Answer (score 1):

No, it should not be like that and it came straight from the factory. Take it to the alignment shop. It's one of the things they do when they align the front end is to ensure the wheel is straight when they are done (or at least they should do that). Tell them when you take it in to have it done what's going on. Also, considering it's off as much as it is, it probably needs an alignment anyway.

Comment: I didn't mean, that the wheel was not straight. What I meant, was that after a corner, the wheels and the steering wheel should (to some degree) return to a straight position by itself thanks to positive caster alignment in the front suspension geometry.

Comment: Again, an alignment should fix the issue. If it doesn't, there's problems with the suspension which need to be addressed. Good alignment shops will tell you if there are issues with the car which would require attention.